# Doctrine Date Format

Tags: php, symfony-2, doctrine-2

Eu gostaria de formatar uma data com Doctrine, muitas vezes eu salvo uma data como datetime no banco de dados porém quero realizar uma busca agrupando por dia sem considerar minutos e segundos. Alguém sabe uma forma legal de fazer isso ?

Comment: Para fazer isso com SQL comum é bem fácil e com DQL também o seria – acredito que seja só fazer um `GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(data, "%Y-%m-%d")`. Já tentou?

Comment: Já tentei, até onde eu sei não existe DATE_FORMAT para Doctrine, vim até aqui na esperança de descobrir algum bundle que tenha criado essa função DQL

Comment: Que tipo de consulta você está tentando fazer? Normalmente usamos DQL quando queremos traduzir o resultset de uma consulta nas entidades da aplicação, mas como você quer trazer um resultado agrupado (por causa do `GROUP BY`), seria mais interessante executar um SQL nativo (por meio do próprio Doctrine).

Comment: Na verdade DQL é uma linguagem de consulta para seu modelo de objetos, ou seja para você não ficar escrevendo nome de tabelas ou ter que se preocupar com seu modelo de dados. O result set é independente de ser DQL ou SQL, não queria ter que escrever uma query nativa =(. Estava pensando em deixar dois campos na minha entidade um date e outro time, mas não sei se isso é valido

Comment: Na verdade quando você executa um DQL, o resultset é um objeto (ou um conjunto de objetos) da sua aplicação. Quando você executa um SQL, o resultset é um array. Pessoalmente, não vejo nenhum problema em usar as duas técnicas, que pra mim seriam mais complementares do que conflitantes. Me parece que seu problema se resolve com um SQL mesmo. :)

Comment: Ok, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O doctrine ainda não possui toda a gama de funções do SQL, eles estão trabalhando nisso para futuras versões segundo o [cookbook](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html). Até lá você tem que criar as funções que lhe faltam, no meu caso crie a função DATE

```
namespace ByteinCoffee\ExtraBundle\Doctrine\DQL;

use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker;

/**
 * @author Fábio Lemos Elizandro <fabio@elizandro.com.br>
 * 
 * DateFunction ::= "DATE" "(" ArithmeticPrimary ")"
 */
 class Date extends FunctionNode
 {

     public $dateExpression = null;

     public function parse(Parser $parser)
     {
         $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
         $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);
         $this->dateExpression = $parser->ArithmeticPrimary();
         $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
     }

     public function getSql(SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
     {
         return \sprintf('DATE(%s)', $this->dateExpression->dispatch($sqlWalker));
     }

 }
```

para registrar a função

```
 doctrine:

    #......

    orm:
        dql:
            datetime_functions:
                date: ByteinCoffee\ExtraBundle\Doctrine\DQL\Date
```

Se alguém conhecer um bundle que faça isso deixe como resposta também. Obrigado